Suppose there is no friction force to balance Coriolis force?
Question 1: Why in rotating frames, is it necessary that an object's acceleration is always directed radially outwards in the $\hat{r}$ direction and why is there no component in the tangential direction?
Question 2: In the equation
$$ m \frac{d^2 \vec{r}}{d t^2} = \vec{F}_{\text{real}} - \vec{F}_{\text{Coriolis}} - \vec{F}_{\text{centrifugal}} -\vec{F}_{\text{Euler}},$$
suppose there is no real force to balance Coriolis force (which is, say, tangential)… but the LHS of the equation has a term only in the r^ direction. How did I generate a contradiction or is there any flaw?
Please help, I am not able to understand rotating frames.

This might help you understand Coriolis force - Coriolis Force: Direction Perpendicular to Rotation Axis Visualization

The straightforward answer is that there is no reason, in general, for $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}$ to only be in the radial direction. Derivatives of $\mathbf{r}$ can have both radial and tangential components. So your "contradiction" starts from a false premise.
Furthermore, none of the above has anything to do with whether there are real forces balancing the Coriolis force.
